# Retool Addasalesdata failed: the caller did not have permission

Tags: google-sheets, retool

Addasalesdata failed (1.659s):The caller does not have permission
Addasalesdata

from Addasalesdata response(Addasalesdata)

▶
in Addasalesdata.trigger()(Addasalesdata)

I tried to append the data in their given google sheet, I followed a tutorial from freecodecamp on CRM

Answer (score 0):

Since the course is years old, we have to copy the whole data, share it with anyone with a link, and re-authorize it. This will append the data.